# Loop not stopping or not starting

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I am making a small userscript for a survey site. Whenever I click the survey and it is indicated that I did not receive it the script is supposed to refresh a certain amount of times trying to claim the survey until it gives up.
(If you do not know what a userscript is, think of it as something that stays running all the time on a specific website, so you can control things using javascript selectors and stuff)

This is my script so far (the javascript portion as that is what the problem is in):

```js
var elementExists = document.getElementsByClassName("message warning")[0];


if(elementExists)
{
    var attempts = 0;
    while(attempts<5)
    {
        attempts += 1;
        location.reload();
        if(elementExists)
        {
            //nothing
        }
        else
        {
            window.stop();
        }

    }
    window.stop();
}
```

This is actually my first time using Javascript so I assumed that would be the reason for errors, but after 45 minutes of debugging I am completely baffled. If I remove that last "window.stop();" the code refreshes the webpage infinitely. If that stays there then the code doesn't even start. It seems almost as if the while loop is being skipped if the "window.stop();" is present. Is this something that Javascript does, or is the problem elsewhere?

If someone could lead me in the right direction or help me fix this I would be very grateful!

(Also I checked the selector to see if that is the issue, but I have done that correctly)

**UPDATE:** Turns out location.reload(); stops the script and thus forces a reload. Since I am creating a userscript I realized that I could use the Greasemonkey APIs (or more like stumbled upon). By using GM_setValue and GM_getValue I was able to work around this problem and the script successfully reloaded a certain amount of times (depending on the variable tries) and stopped when it finished. But after messing around a bit, then reverting to the older version the script, the script doesn't doesn't execute at all anymore; "counter < tries" seems to be false for some reason... could anyone figure out why? Also if documentation is needed:
https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_getValue
https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue

```js
var tries = 5;
var elementExists = document.getElementsByClassName("message warning")[0];
var counter = GM_getValue('counter', 0);

if(elementExists && counter < tries)
{
    GM_setValue('counter', ++counter);
    location.reload();
}
```

(Both counter and tries seem to be integer values.. so there should be in problem in comparing them...)

Also as suggested by @yuriy636 I attempted to reset the variables and created something like this

```js
var tries = 5;
var elementExists = document.getElementsByClassName("message warning")[0];
var counter1 = GM_getValue('counter1', 0);

if(elementExists && counter1 < tries)
{
    GM_setValue('counter1', ++counter1);
    location.reload();
}

if(elementExists && counter1 == tries)
{
    GM_deleteValue('counter1');
    window.close();
}

if(!!elementExists)
{
   GM_deleteValue('counter1');
    return;
    alert("stops script while hidden");
}
```

But again I am hit with the infinite loop.. RIP

**Update 2:** Not so RIP afterall... solution:

```js
var tries = 50;
var elementExists = document.getElementsByClassName("message warning")[0];
var counter = GM_getValue('counter', 0);

if(elementExists && counter < tries)
{
    GM_setValue("counter", counter + 1);
    location.reload();
}
else
{
 GM_deleteValue("counter");
}
if(elementExists && counter >= tries)
{
 window.close();
}
```

100% Working, after indicated amount of tries, if error still exists the page is closed

Comment: `location.reload();` will stop your script immediately, as it's requesting the page to be reloaded.

Comment: The variable values are lost after a reload, so each time your `attempts` is 1 and the page refreshes.

Comment: @MelanciaUK Thank you! Updated with one more problem

Comment: @yuriy636 Thank you! Updated with one more problem

Comment: `"counter < tries" seems to be false for some reason` Maybe because the counter is now greater than 5? After several reloads(and `++counter`s) the value can be greater. Or do you have a reset function to set counter back to 0?

Comment: @yuriy636 I just attempted to create a separate script which executes before this one, spent a few minutes accessing variables of the main script, then I realized due to execution order it will forcibly just keep looping the two scripts  E.x.  Counter reset, loop, counter + 1, counter reset, loop, etc. resulting in an infinite loop. There must be a way to accomplish this in one script. If I did the reset along with the main script same thing would happen... Any ideas for a solution?

Comment: Is it possible to refresh the page without having the entire script restart? If I could accomplish that this would be a piece of cake...

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem is that you have `location.reload()` in your while loop. This causes the page to refresh before anything interesting happens in your loop. In this particular code I would expect the page to refresh seemingly infinitely because every time the page refreshes, it will refresh again.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Updated OP with a fixed version, but now I am encountering my last problem (which was not previously mentioned)

Comment: That's happening because you have: `counter1 < tries`. In your current code, `tries` is always greater than `counter1` and thus always triggers a reload. You probably wanted `counter1 > tries`.

Comment: After looking at the refactored code a bit more, I'm asking myself... what are you trying to do exactly? I don't think we'll be able to give you much additional help without a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: "counter1 < tries" triggering a reload is what I want it to do. When the "if(elementExists && counter < tries)" is executed, counter is incremented by 1 and the loop is restarted, when counter is no longer < tries then then statement shouldn't execute. I'll try to explain what this is supposed to do. This script is supposed to reload a site a given amount of times if an alert box is present (elementExists) and when it has finished reloading the amount of times given the script is supposed to stop. Userscripts are always active so I used an if statement.

Comment: Is it possible to refresh the page without having the entire script restart? If I could accomplish that this would be a piece of cake...

Comment: You could store your counter in a cookie. That's pretty much your only option if you need to be able to track a counter across page reloads.

Comment: This counter variable is actually special, it is stored along with the script (it is made with the Greasemonkey API). When I ran it the first time it worked fine, reloaded a certain amount of times then stopped. After that it no longer worked.. I think the variable needs to be reset

Comment: Okay I see, I have a better idea of what you're trying to do now. I think one thing that might be happening is that your incrementer in the GM_setValue isn't working the way you expect it to. Try `GM_setValue("counter1", counter1 + 1);` instead.

Comment: That wasn't the issue, but I finally fixed it.. and got the code to do 100% exactly what I want it to. Quite the puzzle. Posting solution in OP.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that was one problem. The only other change in your new code is checking if counter is greater than or equal to tries.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this would look more like:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("message warning");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  console.log (elements[i]);
}
```

`.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements with the class `message` and/or `warning` which you are capturing only the 1st one `[0]`.  Hope that helps.